# webdriver mouseover in Firefox stopped working

Tags: java, firefox, webdriver, mousehover

I have several menus in the application I test that require a mouse-over of the top menu item, in order to display the rest of the menu (drop it down).

Top menu item looks like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">>        
    <span>Orders</span>
```

I've used these lines of code, without any problems, for the last 3 or 4 months:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[span[text()='Orders']]"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();
```

This would hover over the 'Orders' menu item, and allow me to then select one of the dropped down items.

I am now using FF21 and WebDriver 2.33, and the hover no longer works.  The 'Order' menu item will be hovered over, and the menu will drop down, but also immediately roll up again.  This prevents me from selecting the submenu items.

What I've tried so far:

- added a wait after the above code to allow me to select submenu item:
  didn't work
- enabled native events in the firefox profile I am using:
  no change in behavior

Any help greatly appreciated, since I am dead in the water without a working menu system.

BTW: This code *does* work in IE, so it seems to be a FF-specific problem?

Comment: When the menu rolls back up, is the mouse still positioned over the 'Orders' menu item - or has it moved away? Also, obvious question but we have to ask: do you have the same problem in FF21 when you test manually?

Comment: I can confirm the issue exists in FF21 + selenium-webdriver 2.33. I've also found a bug for that https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4893

Comment: @vincebowdren : works fine manually.  The cursor (pointer) isn't visible when using webdriver

Comment: @zerkms : thanks for the pointer to that defect.  Although the developers only seem to think it's 'medium' priority :-p

Answer (score 1):

Based on Selenium's changelog (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG) it seems that native events (as you are using Actions class) are supported only in Firefox 20.
Please, loot at changelog for v2.32.0. There is a line:

> "This release supports Firefox verions: 10esr, 17esr, 19, 20"

Changelog for v2.33.0 does not have anything that says about supporting Firefox 21.

Try your code with Firefox 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following java script. It worked in our project. Hopefully it works for you as well... Cheers...

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
         + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
         ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.driver).executeScript(javaScript, element);
```